# Taking a derivative of an eigenvector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics, eigenvalues

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of an eigenvector that I obtain by

```
matrix[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, ...]:={...};];
eigenV[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, ...]:= Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[Chop[Eigensystem[N[matrix[x,y,...]]]]], First];
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
ND[eigenV[x, ...][[2, 1]], x, 0.2]
```

I get

```
Eigensystem::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors.
{0., 0., 0., 0.}
```

However, I can evaluate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors at this (and any other) point numerically with no problem.
Is there another way to force `Eigensystem[]` to evaluate numerically when it is wrapped in `ND[]`?

The derivative obviously works on a minimal 2x2 example, presumably because symbolic evaluation is trivial. MWE:

```
 matrix[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]:={{-c + b x + a z, a (x - I y)}, {a (x + I y), -c + b x - a z}};
```

It doesn't work when it's 4x4, which technically should also be symbolically tractable, but whose matrix elements are more complicated.

```
 matrix[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ ]:=
 {{-a + b (1 + d) - (-1 + d) Sqrt[-c^2 (-6 + 2 Cos[y] Cos[z] + 2 Cos[x] (Cos[y] + Cos[z]) + 8 Cos[z/2] (Cos[y/2] Sin[x/2]^2 + Cos[x/2] Sin[y/2]^2) + 8 Cos[x/2] Cos[y/2] Sin[z/2]^2)], f + E^(-(1/2) I (x + y)) g + E^(-(1/2) I (x + z)) g + E^(-(1/2) I (y+z)) g, 0, 0}, 
{f + (E^(1/2 I (x + y)) + E^(1/2 I (x + z)) + E^(1/2 I (y + z))) g, -a-b+b d - 2 (1 + d) Sqrt[c^2 ((Cos[y/2] - Cos[z/2])^2 Sin[x/2]^2 + (Cos[x/2] - Cos[z/2])^2 Sin[y/2]^2 + (Cos[x/2] - Cos[y/2])^2 Sin[z/2]^2)], 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, -a + b + b d - 2 (1 + d) Sqrt[c^2 ((Cos[y/2] - Cos[z/2])^2 Sin[x/2]^2 + (Cos[x/2] - Cos[z/2])^2 Sin[y/2]^2 + (Cos[x/2] - Cos[y/2])^2 Sin[z/2]^2)], 
f + E^(-(1/2) I (x + y)) g + E^(-(1/2) I (x + z)) g + E^(-(1/2) I (y + z)) g}, 
{0, 0, f + (E^(1/2 I (x + y)) + E^(1/2 I (x + z)) + E^(1/2 I (y + z))) g, -a - (-1 + d) (-b +Sqrt[-c^2 (-6 + 2 Cos[y] Cos[z] + 2 Cos[x] (Cos[y] + Cos[z]) + 
     8 Cos[z/2] (Cos[y/2] Sin[x/2]^2 + Cos[x/2] Sin[y/2]^2) + 
     8 Cos[x/2] Cos[y/2] Sin[z/2]^2)])}};
```

My eventual desired size is 8x8.

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean `matrix[v_]:= ...`? Even better may be to supress any symbolic evaluation with `eigenV[v_?NumericQ] :=...` and to call `ND[eigenV[{x, 1.2, 2.}], x, .2]` instead. This works at least with the toy example `n = 8;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]; A = A\[Transpose].A;
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]; B = B\[Transpose] + B;
matrix[v_] := A + v B;
eigenV[v_?NumericQ] := 
  Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[Chop[Eigensystem[N[matrix[v]]]]], First];`.

Comment: Given the error (unable to find eigenvalues) it seems the problem lies in the calculation of the eigenvalues, not in the taking of the derivative. Can you give an example of the matrix? Maybe it does not have distinct eigenvalues (which might cause the eigensystem to not have eigenvectors).

Comment: It is worth checking that your matrix is exactly numerically Hermitian. Problems can arise if matrices are non-Hermitian through rounding errors.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Once parameters are plugged in, the matrix has eigenvectors and eigenvalues in the relevant domain.

Comment: @induvidyul Without the actual matrices or the function that produces them, nothing can be said.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I've revised my question to hopefully be more clear and with working and non-working examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the proplem is this: Since `eigenV` stays unevaluated when called with symbolic arguments, `[[2, 1]]` operates on the *expression* `eigenV[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8][[2, 1]]`, not on the matrix that you obtain from inserting a numerical value of `x`. For example

```
eigenV[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8][[x]]
```

evaluates to `x`.

So, the following works just fine:

```
eigenV1[
   x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ,
   a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ,
   d_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ
   ] := Transpose[
    SortBy[Transpose[
      Chop[Eigensystem[N[matrix[x, y, z, a, b, c, d, f, g]]]]], 
     First]][[2, 1]];
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
ND[eigenV[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], x, 0.2]
```

> {0.132818 + 0.122787 I, -0.00136903, 0., 0.}